# Iscroll5 how to turn this scroller from vertical to horizontal?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am working on an iscroll5 scroller,have been stuck on this for a while now.

I am trying to create multiple scroller that uses class instead of id. I managed to do that and create the scroller from examples, but for some reason i can only get them in verticals, but not horizontals. Wondering if anyone can help me make the vertical scroller into horizontal ones.

Vertical scroller
http://jsfiddle.net/GuCC2/25/

```
<div id="54" class="myclass">
    <div class="scroller">

            <div class="slide" style="background-color:green;">

            </div>
            <div class="slide" style="background-color:blue;">

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
      <br />
      <br />
<div id="wrappertwo" class="myclass">
    <div class="scroller">


               <div class="slide" style="background-color:red;"></div>
          <div class="slide" style="background-color:green;"></div>
          <div class="slide" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
          <div class="slide" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>


        </div>
    </div>
```

Horizontal one that scrolls, but can not successfully transfer it to the vertical scroll, it simply stops scrolling. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/hbdg020g7m5q5LuUNTll?p=preview

I can manage to put them into horizontal format, but they don't scroll horizontally, just vertically even in the javascript, i set scrollX: true,
example
http://jsfiddle.net/GuCC2/27/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```js
var iScroll = function () {
    $('[data-iscroll]').each(function () {
        $(this).wrapInner("<div class='scroller'></div>")
            .wrapInner("<div class='wrapper'></div>");

        var wrapper = $(this).find('.wrapper'),
            windowHeight = $(window).height();

        wrapper.height(windowHeight);

        function iScrollStart() {
            var scroller = new IScroll(wrapper.get(0), {
                eventPassthrough: false,
                scrollX: true,
                scrollY: true,
                preventDefault: false,
                scrollbars: true,
                mouseWheel: true
            });
        }

        window.myScroll = iScrollStart();
    });

    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
}();
```

```css
.slide, .scroller {
    width: 1000px;
}
.slide {
    background: #222;
    color: white;
    font: 50px Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 50px;
}
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.scroller {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/cubiq/iscroll/master/build/iscroll.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide" data-iscroll>Vertical slider</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/zqo506c5/

Comment: Thanks for the help, but in your snippet, i can't do slide as 100% width of screen tho, i am trying to get mine as 100% of the screen width. Because i want each slide as the screen's width, and the data coming in is dynamic data. I wouldn't be able to set a static width. But this fix manage to do that http://plnkr.co/edit/hbdg020g7m5q5LuUNTll?p=preview But then now it wont scroll horizontally on mine, but it will on theirs

Comment: You never mentioned that in your question. Either way, sounds like you have to set screen width via jQuery / jQM.

Comment: Sorry about that. Yer because i got that part working, in my fiddle. Everythings working, except it wont scroll horizontally.Will snap, will scroll vertically, can use class and slide width to 100%, just not horizontal scroll for some reason.